# C# with Linq XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm a newbie, could someone please help me what type is the "Parts", I am unable to find the correct type and hence can't return the object "Parts". Thanks

```
private ???? load_parts()
{
     var element = XElement.Load("xml/suras.xml");
     **var** Parts= from var in element.Descendants("part")
                 orderby var.Attribute("index").Value
                 select new  dictSuras
                 {
                     PartIndex = Convert.ToInt32(var.Attribute("index").Value),
                     PartPosition = Convert.ToInt32(var.Attribute("position").Value),
                     PartName = var.Attribute("name").Value
                 };

     return  Parts;
 }
```

Comment: You might also consider using the `XAttribute` explicit casting operators. For example, in doing so the line for `PartIndex` becomes: `PartIndex = (int)var.Attribute("index"),` which is not only less code, but the code that is gone was noisy ceremonial type code, what's left is IMO meaty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're selecting a `new dictSuras`, the return value is an `IEnumerable<dictSuras>`.

Comment: @saafh, a word of advice: I highly recommend you check out ReSharper.  It's great for things like this.  With a single keystroke, you can convert your `var` declaration to the "real" type (in this case, `IEnumerable<dictSuras>`.  I find it a huge boon, and it's exceedingly popular.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than an answer that gives the information the OP is looking for, I will give an answer that shows how to find it. It is easier for all of us I think.

In Visual Studio, if you mouse-over a variable, a tooltip is displayed that includes the variable's type. This is quite useful if you are like me and dislike `var`, as it lets you see at a glance what the actual type is.

Comment: +1, but it's useful if people aren't like you and *do* like `var` as well!

Comment: Indeed a very useful tip! I've been programming c#+wp7 programming only since yesterday :)